# Querying a store in dojo to find a number that is less than a given number

Tags: javascript, dojo

Given an example in http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/util/SimpleQueryEngine

```
SimpleQueryEngine(function(object){
    return object.id > 1;
})(someData) // Returns an array with matching objects
```

Im using **DataStore** http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/store/DataStore

DataStore contains a store of type **ItemFileWriteStore** http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore

I'm trying the following:

```
var myNumber = 12; // but could be any number like -12, 0.12, 12345 or -12345.1
dataStore.store.query(function(storeItem){
    return storeItem.number < myNumber;
})
```

and that doesn't really work.

As far as I can see SimpleQueryEngine uses dojo/_base/array which uses a filter method that takes in parameters such as an array and callback function to filter by.

As you can see here: https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/store/DataStore.js, DataStore uses SimpleQueryEngine so it should work...

My store contains objects like this:

```
[{id: 1, number: 2345},{id: 2, number: 23.45},{id: 3, number: -2345},{id: 4, number: 2345},{id: 5, number: 0.2345}]
```

I would like to query given store to find a number that is less than a given number.

And to clarify what I'm really trying to understand is why passing in a function as a parameter to query() method doesn't work and how to make it work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Since you have an `ItemFileWriteStore`, you could use it's function called `fetch`. It might be able to do what you need. Let's say `store` is your `ItemFileWriteStore`, you would do:

```
store.fetch({
   sort: [{attribute: "number", descending: true}]
   onComplete: function(items, request) {
      // items will be an array of the items in your store, 
      // sorted by the "number" attributed in descending order
   }
});
```

In your `onComplete` function you would have the array of sorted store items in descending order based on the number parameter. At this point it would be trivial to find *all* numbers that are less than your specified number (rather than just 1 as you stated).

Comment: you can also get all items with dataStore.store.query(), but thats not it. Just to clarify dataStore.store - DataStore, dataStore.store.store - ItemFileWriteStore.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you're trying to do? With the sort parameter you would have all the items sorted by "number". In other words, you could then easily loop through and compare "item[i]" to "myNumber" and store it if it's less than myNumber. Once you're above "myNumber" you stop looping. Is that not the end goal or did I misunderstand?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to pass a function as a parameter to dataStore.store.query() method that will do all the filtering also I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work, sorry about the confusion I'll update my question

Comment: Okay I understand what you're asking now. If you look at the comments on the code for the page you linked (https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/store/DataStore.js), you'll notice that the function query takes the parameter "query" that is an object, not a function. So I'm not sure you can do this the way that you're trying to...

Comment: Yeah you can pass in an object with parameter name and value that can be a regex also, and also I'm quite certain you can overwrite query method. As far as I can see it's returning a Deferred object, but you can overwrite a queryEngine along with preferred return value when creating an instance of DataStore... @Eric Alberson thanks anyways I really appreciate your help.